# Django - Symmetrical relation OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing and app to manage my network equipments. I created a model, RJ45port, which I can add to my equipment as needed. A RJ45port can be plugged into an other RJ45port and only one.

Here is the model I created :

```py
class RJ45port(models.Model):
    plugged_into = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

When I "plug" a RJ45port into another, I want the second one to have "plugged_into" set to the first one. I want the relation to be symmetrical. If I "unplug", I want both of the RJ45 ports to have "plugged_into" set to null, or blank.

I found a bit of code, it might be a hint :

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RJ45port, self).save()    
    self.plugged_into.plugged_into = self
```

To be honest I'm a bit lost here and it's the final step I need to get this app functional...

Answer (score 1):

You are best suited just making a model `plug_into()` method, and then using it to "plug" one instance into another, as well as an `unplug()` method.

Example:

```
class RJ45port(models.Model):
    plugged_into = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def plug_into(self, instance):
        self.plugged_into = instance
        instance.plugged_into = self

        self.save(update_fields=['plugged_into'])
        instance.save(update_fields=['plugged_into'])
        return [self.plugged_into, instance.plugged_into]

    def unplug(self):
        self.plugged_into.plugged_into = None
        self.plugged_into = None

        self.plugged_into.save(update_fields=['plugged_into'])
        self.save(update_fields=['plugged_into'])
        return [self.plugged_into, instance.plugged_into]
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
port_1 = Port.objects.all()[0]  # First port
port_2 = Port.objects.all()[1]  # Second port
port_1.plug_into(port_2)  # Should return [instance, instance]
port_1.unplug()  # Should return [None, None]
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, but how do I call plug_into and unplug in my admin page ?

Comment: @vjuluss I would override the admin `save_model()` method to call the `plug_int()` and `unplug()` methods. An example can be shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21852651/3345051

Comment: if self.plugged_into, call plug_into,    else call unplug ?

Comment: @vjuluss I would check if the instance has changed, and if it did, call `obj.plug_into()` or `obj.unplug()` depending on if there is a new value for `obj.plugged_into`. You can see how to do it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056179/django-admin-save-model-method-how-to-detect-if-a-field-has-changed/26001986

Comment: Well I can't make it work... souldn't work on problem like this at the end of the day...

Comment: @vjuluss No problem! Sometimes you need to take a break to get a clear mind. I would like to help you more, but it becomes very difficult since I don't have a good testing environment. You should give it another try soon, and can always ask another question regarding overriding `save_model()` in django admin (which I know very little about). Hopefully someone can help you tackle that second part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Simply override the save method. But call `super().save()` at the end:

```
class RJ45port(models.Model):
    plugged_into = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        self.plugged_into.plugged_into = self
        super(RJ45port, self).save()
```

Comment: There are three issues with this. 1) `self.plugged_into.plugged_into` is never saved, 2) There is a race condition if you *do* use `self.plugged_into.plugged_into.save()` - which will happen first, the `.save()` of the secondary instance, or the initial instance? 3) There will be a loop of infinite `save()` methods calling each other

Comment: The problem with this is when I want to "unplug", Django returns an error saying that None has no object "plugged_into"

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a `related_name` so you can make a reverse access from the referenced instance, so you can say that the relationship becomes "symetrical". The only downside is that you can't use the same name to reference both connections:

```
class RJ45port(models.Model):
    plugged_into = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='plugged_from')
```

In this example, `plugged_from` can be queried like any other field from the referenced instance.

Comment: I think I understand your suggestion. I could give it a try later when I can code. But I don't think this will show the reverse connexion in the admin interface... ?